# Which of these sentences is better to say a dog had it's leg removed?

Tags: expressions, writing

My friend's little dog was hit by a vehicle some time last week, and the dog's right leg was badly injured and had to be removed (by a veterinary).

When I want to tell other people this news, which of these sentences is better?

1. XXX's little dog had its right leg removed.
2. xxx's little dog's right leg was removed.

Thank you.

Comment: Both of these are fine. I wouldn't recommend one of them over the other.

Comment: I'm not sure but by 'had its right leg removed' I get the impression of a conscious choice. i.e the dog actually agreed to and made preparations of the romoval of its leg by someone else. I think the second sentence is more logical.

Comment: "had" does not always suggest volition or conscious choice.  The house had its roof replaced last year.

Comment: The car had its oil changed every 5000 miles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb is **amputate**, the noun, **amputation**.  The dog had its leg amputated.